# "Redraw" LinearLayout view to change option

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, builder

I'm trying to change attribute to custom `LinearLayout` class, I set the option to class with:

```
MyBuilder option = new MyBuilder.Builder()
.image(...)
.setCardRadius(...)
.build());
```

Than i call in `MainActivity`

```
MyObject obj = (MyObject) findViewById(R.id.myObject); 
obj.init(context, option);
```

But if I call multiple times `obj.init(...)` with different `option` the builder has old value setted so the view cannot change attribute correctly.

So my question is: can I reset `Builder` o `LinearLayout` before initializate new object?

This is my **LinearLayout.java**:

```
public class MyObject extends LinearLayout{
    CardView card;
    ImageView image;
    float cardRadiusAttr;
    View rootView;
    AttributeSet attributeSet;

    public void init(final Context context, final MyBuilder option){
        if(option != null)
        {
         /*
        Get attribute from XML
         */
            TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeSet, R.styleable.Card, 0, 0);
            try {
                cardRadiusAttr = ta.getDimension(R.styleable.Card_c_cardRadius, option.getCardRadius());

            } finally {
                ta.recycle();
            }

        /*
        Set up xml object.
         */
            card = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card);
            image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

            card.setRadius(cardRadiusAttr);

            /**
             * Check if Option is set
             */
            if (option.isImage() != null) {

              //Set Image

            }
        }else{
            Log.e("Initialization", "Option View not initialize!");
        }
    }


    public MyObject(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        /*
        Inflater custom layout to view.
         */
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Card, this, true);
        attributeSet = attrs;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
    }

}
```

This is **MyBuilder.java**

```
public class MyBuilder {
    private int mImage;
    private float mCardRadius = 4f;

    private MyBuilder(Builder builder)
    {
        mImage = builder.mImage;
        mCardRadius = builder.mCardRadius;
    }

    public static class Builder{
        private int mImage;
        private float mCardRadius = 4f;

        public Builder setCardRadius(float radius)
        {
            if(radius <= 0)
            {
                Log.e("CardRadius", "Impossible to set Card Radius lower than 0! Please Check it");
            }
            else {
                mCardRadius = radius;
            }
            return this;
        }

        public Builder image(int image) {

            if(image == 0)
            {
                Log.e("Image", "Impossible to set Image to 0! Please Check it");
            }
            else {
                mImage = image;
            }
            return this;
        }

        public MyBuilder build() {
            return new MyBuilder(this);
        }

    }

    public int getImage() {
        return mImage;
    }

    public float getCardRadius() {
        return mCardRadius;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the builder uses old values? Or the view is not redrawn according to new params?

Comment: I'm sure the builder has the old parameters @CristianHoldunu

Comment: Please show your whole custom LinearLayout

Comment: sure, it's simplified @ligi

Comment: I don't get:  what `MyBuilder` is? What `MyObject` is? How you "call multiple times obj.init"?  My best guess so far is that issue in the `MyBuilder`. And you option object is remaining the same.

Comment: MyObject is the class up here (i've edit) and MyBuilder is a class for set option, I use builder pattern for do this, and everything work if i call obj.init(context, firstTime) once, but if in the same class I call init(context, differentOption) i see the object setted in the firstTime wich overlap differentOption object @KonstantinLoginov

Comment: @MicheleLacorte ok, getting clearer. I bet, MyBuilder contains the issue then. You mean, that `init` method get's firstTime object even when you call `init(context, differentOption)`, right? Then `differentOption` is not actually a new object, but the old one, obviously

Comment: And also, first code snippet, isn't `option` supposed to be `OptionView`, not `MyBuilder`?

Comment: OptionView is MyBuilder sorry and yes the problem it's this! but i tried more thing but nothing MyBuilder remains the old!! @KonstantinLoginov

Comment: Then you issue in MyBuilder. Without seeing it, it's impossible to say, what exact wrong with it.

Comment: I've edit @KonstantinLoginov

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102090/discussion-between-konstantin-loginov-and-michele-lacorte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the issue.

In the `init` method of the `MyObject` you have to **clean up the View after the previous use**.

In this particular case, first, you pass one set of options. Based on them, View is adjusting `Visibility` of its controls (making `button1`, `button2`, etc. `Visible`). But when you pass **another** set of options - you have to erase all changes have been made before. (i.e. hide `button1`, `button2`, etc. and let the View to adjust `Visibility` of its controls once again)